# Website for scheduling and submitting homework

Tags: teaching, website, homework

I'm looking for a website where I could publish homework at a scheduled time to a group of students and also allow them to submit their answers through it.

The homework is a single PDF file, and the answers should be a zipped set of files. It would be great if I could also be notified when someone submits their answer.

Comment: N.B. the most common solution to this is an in-house LMS ([learning management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system)), such as as Blackboard. Does your institution use any service like that?

Comment: or [ILIAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILIAS)

Comment: ...or Canvas, or Compass, or Moodle, or Gradescope, or Google Classroom, of any number of other options. I think this is off-topic as a "shopping" question.

Comment: You could even schedule a bulk email to send at a specific time and receive submissions by email, or even ftp’d into a specific location - had a prof who got us to do that...

Comment: I'm looking for something much simpler than a full management system. Don't want to kill a fly with a sledgehammer and also want to avoid a big implementation process.